# Is apt upgrade ; apt update for a fresh raspian buster lite install a default during a 1st boot?

Tags: software-installation, raspbian-buster

I'm installing `2020-08-20-raspios-buster-armhf-lite`.  I normally do this headless, but I happen to have a monitor this time.  It's spending a LOT of time on what appears to be an update/upgrade.  Here's are the last three lines of the log.

```
[ OK ] Started Daily apt download activities
       Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
[ OK ] Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
```

It never got past this point.

I don't remember versions from 2 years ago doing that.  Is this new-ish?  Can it be disabled for that 1st boot?

I expect update/upgrade to take a long time, but I just don't want it done until I'm ready to do it headless.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. If I flash a RaspiOS image it first boot as usual without update/upgrade. I have to do it manual executing `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: @Ingo, edited question to include log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `apt-daily-upgrade.service` called with the `apt-daily-upgrade.timer` every day. I don't know why it make problems on your installation. Anyway, you don't want to run it automatically. You can disable the timer with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl disable apt-daily-upgrade.timer
```

The problem is that you can't do it because the boot get stuck on executing the service. When I look at the service with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl cat apt-daily-upgrade.service
# /lib/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.service
[Unit]
Description=Daily apt upgrade and clean activities
Documentation=man:apt(8)
ConditionACPower=true
After=apt-daily.service network.target network-online.target systemd-networkd.service NetworkManager.service connman.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre=-/usr/lib/apt/apt-helper wait-online
ExecStart=/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily install
KillMode=process
TimeoutStopSec=900
```

I see that the service will timeout (**TimeoutStopSec**) after 900 seconds, that are 15 minutes. So boot your RasPi and wait at least 15 min. Maybe the RasPi will continue booting and you are able to disable the timer.

If you want to disable the timer before first booting you must mount the second **ext4** root partition of the CD Card on a computer with a linux operating system. Other operating systems are not able to mount **ext4**. If you have mounted the root partition to e.g. `/mnt/` then you can disable the `apt-daily-upgrade.timer` by deleting a symlink:

```
pc ~$ sudo rm /mnt/etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/apt-daily-upgrade.timer
```

Comment: can this be done such that it is disabled during the 1st boot? thx

Comment: @MACE Yes, you can. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else coming across this issue, you can try inputting your username to login and pressing enter. If it responds with a password prompt, just continue on logging in, and everything seems to be okay. FWIW, this was installing RaspiOS 10 'Buster' onto an old (2011) Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2.0